# Inversion count value of inversion in merge sort

Tags: c++, c, count, mergesort, inversion

The following below is a code to count inversions in a an array.I have a doubt in this part:

```
     inv_count  = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid);--i

    inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid+1, right);--ii

     inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid+1, right);--iii
```

In inversion count ,the total inversion will be equal to i+ii +iii  ,but I am unable to understand how does "the inv_count of i and ii even getting a value , they are called recursively and filled into function stack but nowhere the value is imparted to inv_count
for i and ii,though in iii ,inv_count is getting value using invcount=inv_count+mid-i;

```
   int mergeSort(int arr[], int array_size)
{
    int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*array_size);
    return _mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, array_size - 1);
}

/* An auxiliary recursive function that sorts the input array and
  returns the number of inversions in the array. */
int _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right)
{
  int mid, inv_count = 0;
  if (right > left)
  {
    /* Divide the array into two parts and call _mergeSortAndCountInv()
       for each of the parts */
    mid = (right + left)/2;

    /* Inversion count will be sum of inversions in left-part, right-part
      and number of inversions in merging */
    inv_count  = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid);

    inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid+1, right);

    /*Merge the two parts*/
    inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid+1, right);
  }
  return inv_count;
}

/* This funt merges two sorted arrays and returns inversion count in
   the arrays.*/
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
  int i, j, k;
  int inv_count = 0;

  i = left; /* i is index for left subarray*/
  j = mid;  /* i is index for right subarray*/
  k = left; /* i is index for resultant merged subarray*/
  while ((i <= mid - 1) && (j <= right))
  {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
    {
      temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      temp[k++] = arr[j++];

     /*this is tricky -- see above explanation/diagram for merge()*/
      inv_count = inv_count + (mid - i);
    }
  }

  /* Copy the remaining elements of left subarray
   (if there are any) to temp*/
  while (i <= mid - 1)
    temp[k++] = arr[i++];

  /* Copy the remaining elements of right subarray
   (if there are any) to temp*/
  while (j <= right)
    temp[k++] = arr[j++];

  /*Copy back the merged elements to original array*/
  for (i=left; i <= right; i++)
    arr[i] = temp[i];

  return inv_count;
}
```

Comment: I found nice implementation here http://www.kodemonk.com/invcnt-inversion-count/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for inversion count.--i --ii --iii has nothing to do with inversion count.

The total number of inversions during merge sorting is equal to the sum of the inversion obtained from sorting left part and sorting right part and merging the left part with right part.If you are not clear with the code then please do comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int size = 1000000;
long long int array[size];
long long int merge(long long int a[], long long int beg, long long int mid,
    long long int end) {
    long long int inverse = 0;
    long long int lsize = (mid - beg) + 1;
    long long int rsize = (end - mid);
    long long int left[lsize + 1];
    long long int right[rsize + 1];
    long long int i;
    long long int j = beg;
    for (i = 0; i < lsize; ++i, ++j) {
        left[i] = a[j];
    }
    j = mid + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < rsize; ++i, ++j) {
        right[i] = a[j];
    }
    left[lsize] = LONG_LONG_MAX;
    right[rsize] = LONG_LONG_MAX;
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (int k = beg; k <= end; ++k) {
       if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            a[k] = left[i];
            ++i;
       } else {
            a[k] = right[j];
            inverse += (lsize - i);
            ++j;
      }
    }
   return inverse;
}

long long int merge_sort(long long int iArray[], long long int beg,
        long long int end) {
     if (beg < end) {
        long long int mid;
        long long int left = 0;
        long long int right = 0;
        long long int total = 0;
        mid = (beg + end) / 2;
        left = merge_sort(iArray, beg, mid);
        right = merge_sort(iArray, mid + 1, end);
        total = merge(iArray, beg, mid, end);
        return left + right + total;
     } else {
         return 0;
     }
}
```